# How to activate ng-submit from a timer call-back?

Tags: angularjs

I have a timer that would re-submit the page at intervals. Is there an angular way to do that?

Right now I was just submitting the form inside a script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
    window.setTimeout( function () {
        document.getElementById( "srchForm" ).submit();
    }, 300000 );    //5 min  
</script>
<form id="srchForm" ng-controller="OutageViewController" ng-submit="loadData(0)">
<p id="div_srchForm"> ....</p>
<button id="btnReload" type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

but it would give me 404 error status:

404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Comment: I recommend a different approach - use a `$timeout()` in the controller. It looks like all you are attempting to do is to refresh the data being displayed and doing this from the controller instead of the view seems more appropriate. Even better would be to implement something like SignalR to push updated data to the connected clients when there is fresh data to display.

Comment: actually ng-submit is not the 'submit' submit: it is in fact an AJAX call to a function that partial update the form so it is not like reloading the entire form!  So using submit in the callback trying to to do ng-submit is wrong. I have to work around it.  See my findings below.

Comment: OK, but I still think doing this from the controller instead of using some javascript hack on the view is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use $interval service to schedule a function for repeated execution with a time interval in between.

Example that used the $interval service to schedule a function call every 3 seconds:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.loadData = function() {
     console.log("loadData - Interval occurred");
  };
  $interval(function() {
    $scope.loadData();
   }, 3000);
});

<form id="formX" ng-controller="MainCtrl" ng-submit="loadData(0)">
   <p id="div_srchForm"> ....</p>
   <button id="btnReload" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/yqMW9ZENoqZwfDtqlsTy

Comment: The reason I stayed away from using angular timeout is because it only happens once. Now I know why. I have to use $interval for a repeated process!!

Answer (score 1):

I would rather ask why you are trying to simulate a button click in the first place. As others have hinted at, browser automation as a user experience is typically a poor choice and reflects poor organization in your software design. I would recommend using the $timeout already available in Angular to do this from the controller instead. Not only does this put your front end logic where it belongs,in the controller, but also gives you a clean teardown mechanism so your timer doesn't continue I run if the controller isn't active (and prevents you from writing another hack to mitigate that).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a non-Angular way to work around to get to the ng-submit handler:

Looks like I cannot call form.submit in the callback. When I did that, they can't "see" ng-submit and it lost me where the call has taken me when it complained not finding "resources" which is the page itself!  My work-around to connect to the ng-submit is,

Now  instead of doing form.submit in the callback, I click the submit button which is just primitive js but it did the job!

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
    window.setTimeout( function () {
        document.getElementById( "btnReload" ).click();
        //window.location.reload();
    }, 300000 );    //5 min  
</script>
```

The button activated ng-submit because of the way the scope of submit was set up.  Just don't ask me why clicking the button is working but form-submitting is not working!

After all, I still want to know the Angular Way to do it, not my primitive js !!